# Are class VII surfaces uniruled?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

This is likely obvious, but in any case. Let $X$ be a compact non-Kähler surface of negative Kodaira dimension $\kappa(X) = - \infty$. Is $X$ uniruled? In other words,

> For complex surfaces, does the uniruled conjecture extend to the non-Kähler setting?

Comment: Could you include the definition of uniruled?